# I can't quite grasp this transformation our lecturer presented for us.

Tags: complex-analysis

$T_a(z) = \frac{z - a}{\overline{a}z - 1}, \ \textrm{where}\  a = \frac{1}{3}$

He then applied this transformation to two different circles:

$\partial D(0,1) \mapsto \partial D(0,1)$

$\partial D(0,3) \mapsto \{z : \operatorname{Re} z = \frac{5}{3}\}$

I get that the unit circle maps onto itself, but when I try to apply it to the other circle, I dont get the same line. Here is what I did:

$$T_{1/3}(z) = \frac{z-\frac{1}{3}}{z - 3} = \frac{z - \frac{1}{3} - 3 + 3}{z - 3} = 1 + \frac{8}{z-3}$$

$z \mapsto z - 3 : \partial D(0,3)\mapsto\partial D(-3,3)$

$z \mapsto \frac{1}{z} : \partial D(-3,3)\mapsto\{z : \operatorname{Re} z =  -\tfrac{1}{6}\}$

$z \mapsto 8z : \{z: \operatorname{Re} z =  -\tfrac{1}{6}\}\mapsto\{z: \operatorname{Re} z =  -\tfrac{8}{6}\}$

$z\mapsto z+1 : \{z: \operatorname{Re} z = -\tfrac{8}{6}\} \mapsto \{z: \operatorname{Re} z = -\tfrac{2}{6}\}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you want to indicate the boundary of a disk you should probably use $\partial$ instead of $\delta$. I've never seen $\delta$ used with that meaning before. (The LaTeX command is `\partial`.)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm new to this format and I didn't know the command for the correct one! Used delta because it is pretty similar.

Comment: No problem. I've learned half my LaTeX from people posting corrections in the comments here. But you should go back and correct your post to use the right symbol, for people who may read it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simplified the expression for $T$ incorrectly. Note that
$$T_{1/3}(z)=\frac{z-\frac13}{\frac13z-1}$$
$$=\frac{3z-1}{z-3}$$
$$=\frac{3z-9+9-1}{z-3}$$
$$=\frac{3z-9}{z-3}+\frac{8}{z-3}$$
$$=3 + \frac{8}{z-3}$$
You should be able to continue from here.

Comment: Oh, now I feel so stupid. D'oh, thanks!

Comment: It's not stupid, it's an easy mistake to make. You were clearly thinking ahead about clearing fractions and did it mentally without writing it down. It happens to all of us. The moral is: Don't skip steps! Better to write an extra line than to miss the problem